# Bulk Patching of documents in Marklogic database using java client api

Tags: java, marklogic, marklogic-9

I have several json documents like below :-

{
 status : TO_BE_REPORTED,
 date   : 2017/11/11
 ....
}

I want to update or patch the documents by only replacing the status field value from TO_BE_REPORTED to REPORTED and I want to do the bulk update as I have thousands of documents with me. I am using the DocumentPatchBuilder but it doesn't support bulk updates.

On the other hand i can see that Marklogic has few concepts of doing a Bulk write using docManager.newWriteSet and then adding documents to it but it doesn't support document patching?

Are there other things that i can try?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend reading up on the [Data Movement SDK](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/data-movement). It should contain various code snippets on how to do various updates.

HTH!

Comment: Correct, the ApplyTransformListener will allow a QueryBatcher to apply a server-side transform against all documents matching a query or uris provided by an Iterator.  You could easily create a PatchListener that applies a patch on every uri provided by the QueryBatcher.  It would take longer to run since, as you note, there's no bulk call.  But the code shouldn't be too difficult to write and maintain.  And the QueryBatcher will process the documents in multiple threads so it will run much faster than the equivalent for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

[CoRB2](https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2) is a community built tool intended to do bulk updates. You provide a URI module that identifies which documents are to be updated and a processing module to specify what changes are to be made. The modules can be written in either XQuery or JavaScript (I believe that's right; it has always supported XQuery and I think they added JS some time ago). It doesn't use the Java Client API, but should address your need.